# Creating geom_map in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

at the moment I'm trying to build a geom_map of Europe with a color density (based on percentage value). Something like this:

[image]

But for Europe with a German dataset.
e.g. this is a reduced version of my dataset:

```
df <- data.frame( countries = c("Deutschland", "England", "Frankreich","Spanien"), satif = c(84,56,78,89))
```

I already looked up some tutorials for the geom_map (e.g. [http://web.stanford.edu/~imalone/VAM/ggmap.html](http://web.stanford.edu/%7Eimalone/VAM/ggmap.html)), but i couldn't manage to get this thing done. Is it really necessary to search for the long and lat for each country? Is there a automatic method for this task?
Furthermore can ggplot2 handle a German/Europe dataset at all?

thanks for any help!
regards

Answer (score 2):

First you need to get your German Country Names into English. Then you have to merge your data somehow with the world data from map_world without changing the order (with merge it changes the order).

```
require(maps)
require(ggmap)
require(mapproj)

dfworldmap = map_data("world")
df <- data.frame( countries = c("Germany", "UK", "France","Spain"), satif = c(84,56,78,89))


dfworldmap2 = merge(dfworldmap, df, by.x = "region", by.y = "countries")

dfworldmap2 = dplyr::filter(dfworldmap, region %in% unique(df$countries))
dfworldmap2$satif = NA
for(c in unique(df$countries)){
  dfworldmap2[which(dfworldmap2$region == c), "satif"] =
    df[which(df$countries==c), "satif"]
}

ggplot(dfworldmap2) + geom_polygon(aes(long,lat, group=group, fill=satif)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: that looks dope, thank you! But I see a problem in translating the dataset to englisch cause the dataset is imported from a German webpage and has over 40 entries. 
At the moment i just can find packages wich need a google api key or a Microsoft ID - is there simple solution out there without creating a key or something else?

Comment: You probably have to do it by hand, because some countries have abbr. like UK. But if you make a data.frame with a row `de=unique(df$counries)`  and a row en=c("..",...) where the English translations are on the same order as the German Names, you can merge them together and reuse it if you need it again.

Comment: I just looked at the whole dataset and noticed United Kingdom is allready stored as "UK" and not the german "England". The dataset I showed up at the top of the page was written out of my mind.
So maybe there is still an automatic way to translate the countries. At least it is worth a try - I guess.

Comment: You could try to find a country translation list and read it as a data.frame into R. Then you can merge that data.frame with your dataset.